# How can I remove styles-l.css loading for mobile only without mobile theme?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.2

In default, Magento `style-m.css` and `style-l.css` files are loading desktop and mobile screens.

But for `style-l.css`, the chrome inspector shows that `styles-l.css` is 100% unused for mobile. It's affecting speed. So,  am trying to remove this file from the homepage.

So how can we remove this `style-l.css` from mobile without using the Mobile theme?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is affecting the speed of the site?

In default Magento, the `style-l.css` is loading like as shown in the image
[image]

You can see the `style-m.css` comes with a `media="all"` and `style-l.css` comes with `media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"`. This is an important descrimenation to be noted. Because this makes `style-m.css` is always a **render-blocking** asset and `style-l.css` become render-blocking asset only when the `media` query satisfies. i.e, it will become a render blocking asset only on screen larger than `768px`.

Since `style-l.css` is asynchronously loading in mobile devices and not render-blocking, it won't be an issue in terms of speed concern. Actually, reducing the size of `style-m.css` will give much more impact in mobile.

For more reading on this topic, please refer Developers Google's [Render Blocking CSS](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-blocking-css)

If you still want to avoid `style-l.css` loading on mobile devices, then this is possible only through javascript. You need a script like this somewhat.

```
<script>
if (<!mobile_view>) {
   document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/style-l.css" />');
}
</script>
```

Comment: For testing purposes I removed style-l.css in XML. After checking the speed it's improved in terms of unused CSS from GooglePageSpeed. So we need to remove it only for the mobile screen. But I am not able to remove it only for mobile. I have tried using javascript. But it's not worked.